# Vue.js - Use v-for with dynamic range value

Tags: vue.js

Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way ... but I'm trying to use a `v-for` loop to duplicate/remove a custom component `x` times. `x` is decided by a `<select>` field above. What I have works on the initial page load, but then when you select a different option, only one custom component is displayed (although `x` is updated). Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
// here is the select field that defines the number of enrolling students
<select name="number_students_enrolling" v-model="formFields.numberStudentsEnrolling">
    <option value="" default selected></option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

// here is the custom component I'm trying to duplicate/remove dynamically
<div class="students-container">
    <student v-for="n in formFields.numberStudentsEnrolling" :key="n" v-bind:index="n" >
    </student>
</div>

// here is the custom component
Vue.component('student', {
  props: ["index"],
  template: `
    <div class="input--student">
      <div class="input--half">
        <label>
          <span class="d-block">
            Student {{ index }} Name <span class="field--required">*</span>
          </span>
          <input type="text">
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="input-wrap input--half">
        <label>
          <span class="d-block">
            Student {{ index }} DOB <span class="field--required">*</span>
          </span>
          <input type="text">
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  `
})

// Here is the Vue.js instance
var test = new Vue({
  el: '#test',
  data: { 
    formFields: {
      numberStudentsEnrolling: 3
    }
  }
});
```

[image]
  [image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`v-for` needs a `Number`, but you're giving it a string (the selected value).  Convert it to a `Number` so `v-for` will treat it as a range from 1 to N:

```
<div class="students-container">
    <student
        v-for="n in Number(formFields.numberStudentsEnrolling)"
        :key="n"
        v-bind:index="n">
    </student>
</div>
```

For completeness, another approach (per @HusamIbrahim) is to annotate the v-model reference with `.number`, which will automatically do the conversion.

```
<select
    name="number_students_enrolling"
    v-model.number="formFields.numberStudentsEnrolling"
>
```

Here's a codesandbox:  https://codesandbox.io/s/xzy6or9qo

Comment: But `v-for` does work with numbers. In fact [there's a unit test for this feature](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/test/unit/features/directives/for.spec.js) in the codebase. Search `range v-for`.

Comment: @Husam Ibrahim that's why I was confused, because I couldn't get the range v-for feature to display the correct amount of components after the onChange event on the select field.

Comment: @HusamIbrahim Indeed the root cause was the selected value is a string, not a number.  Updated the answer.

Comment: Good catch @JimB.

Comment: @JimB. OP could also use the [.number modifier for v-model](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-model) to automatically cast the input to a number.

Comment: Thanks for all your help.